# Securing IP check php

Tags: php, security, proxy, ip

I have

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM ".MYSQLBTCTABLE." WHERE ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "' AND date = '".date("Y-m-d")."' AND time = '".date("D")."'") or die(mysqli_error());
```

How can I secure the  `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  so it checks not only the user *ip/proxy* but also the socks ip so they can't abuse my code by changing IP?

**also I found this code:**

```
                function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Will it work so if I put `WHERE ip = '".($ip)."'`?

Comment: Your code is wrong. Use backticks (or nothing) to surround table names.

Comment: the .. backticks I've removed from here don't you see that there is etc? the question is about the remote_addr

Comment: Yes, but your code will lead to a syntax error.

Comment: I KNOW my real code is       $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM ".MYSQLBTCTABLE." WHERE ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "' AND date = '".date("Y-m-d")."' AND time = '".date("D")."'") or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Then post your real code. I've seen lots of questions here that couldn't be solved because the OP didn't post real code. Moreover, there are more people that see your question and they might think your code is OK and just copy-paste it.

Comment: How do they abuse your code by changing their IP address? If you provide more detail, we may be able to provide common solutions/best practices.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that in common case

- You can't be sure if user is using proxy: it can be anonymous proxy
- You can't be sure if he is using computer device
- You can't be sure that he is human: it may be request via `cURL` or similar stuff

So that's the reality of the Internet. You can not rely on any information that came from client side. If you're suspecting that user changed his IP address - then hide critical part *behind authentication*. Thus, you'll be able to identify user by his login in your web-application.

Comment: yes but I can be sure they'll have a hard time finding a new Socks proxy :) also I already found the answer before time but I forgot to mention it here